# Two system of linear equation have same solution if

Tags: linear-algebra

Two system of linear equation have same solution if and only if each equation in each system is a linear combination  of the equations in other system?
I didn't get it what are they trying to say?

Comment: It's saying you can get all equations in one system by adding together multiples of the equations in the second system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the system

\begin{align}
x&=1 \tag{1}\\
y&=2 \tag{2}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
x+y&=3 \tag{3}\\
x-y&=-1 \tag{4}
\end{align}

The two system shares the same solution. You can obtain $(3)$ by adding $(1)$ to $(2)$. You can also obtain $(4)$ by  subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$.

You should also recover $(1)$ and $(2)$ from linear combination of $(3)$ and $(4)$.